# Google sign in always ask which accounts to select

Tags: android, google-signin

when i am clicking 1st time on google sign in it ask me which a\c to be selected when more then 1 a]c present . but 2nd time its not asking ,its atomically login with previous   selected  a\c .

how i can always show a\c selected

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) context, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

i tired         mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
 but its given me crash as client not connected

Answer (score 2):

```
You will have to use the revoke access callback.

googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(LoginActivity.this , this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

On the sign in button click

```
 Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 100);
```

In OnActivityResult

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
```

Now you make a function `handleSignInResult(result)` and use the info provided by user.Because in the callback the access will be revoked.
SO here you get the info and do what you want to do.

add this callback to your googleApiCLient

```
  googleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                                    Log.e("getOut",status.toString());
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

            }
        });
```

This call back will revoke access from all the accounts and will show the dialog to select the gmail account everytime.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: onConnected is not called

Comment: signOut should be sufficient for local device, revoke will cause this to happen across devices... https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect